# error while executting the marshalling program?

Tags: java

> how to resolve the exception while excuting a marshalling program 
>   "The method marshal(Book, > FileWriter) is undefined for the type Pool.Marshaller".

```
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.Pool.Marshaller;

 public class BookMarshaller {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
  Book book = new Book("9780312347482", "Power Play", "Joseph Finder");
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("book.xml");
  Marshaller.marshal(book, writer);

  List book2Authors = new ArrayList();
  book2Authors.add("Douglas Preston");
  book2Authors.add("Lincoln Child");
  Book book2 = new Book("9780446618502", "The Book of the Dead",
                        book2Authors);
  writer = new FileWriter("book2.xml");
  Marshaller.marshal(book2, writer);

  } catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
  e.printStackTrace(System.err);
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: how to suggest without knowing what all you doing?

Comment: Could you post the code that is giving you this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `com.sun.xml.ws.util.Pool.Marshaller` - and I guess, you want to use `javax.xml.bind.Marshaller` instead. <strike>Verify</strike> Change your import statement!

`Pool.Marshaller` does not have a `marshal`method.

*And* - like skaffman noted in his comment - `marshal` is not a static method - you need a JAXB context to create a marshaller instance to marshal the book instance.

Comment: That won't work either. `marshal` isn't a static method in either one.

Comment: @skaffman - yeah, you're right, there's more to be done. But `Pool.Marshaller` looks wrong anyway.

Comment: do i need to download any library for such import.javax.xml.bind.Marshaller

Comment: @nit - The `javax.xml.bind` APIs are available in Java SE 6.  You can download individual JAXB (JSR-222) implementation from their respective sites:  JAXB RI (http://jaxb.java.net/), EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), etc

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing your code to the following:

```
package forum9736839;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class BookMarshaller {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Book.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();

            Book book = new Book("9780312347482", "Power Play", "Joseph Finder");
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("book.xml");
            marshaller.marshal(book, writer);

            List book2Authors = new ArrayList();
            book2Authors.add("Douglas Preston");
            book2Authors.add("Lincoln Child");
            Book book2 = new Book("9780446618502", "The Book of the Dead",
                    book2Authors);
            writer = new FileWriter("book2.xml");
            marshaller.marshal(book2, writer);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

}
```